# Is there a jQuery plugin for conditionally disabling forms (not submit)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery 1.7.2.

I don't want to prevent form submission. I want to simulate the disabled attribute for all the inputs. Possibly adding and removing this attribute.

I have a form with an input and submit:

```
<form name="login" id="login" method="post" action="">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input class="text" id="password" name="password" />
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Further down the page a have another form, one which I want to block unless the login form is filled out.

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
    <label>Enter Phone Number</label>
    <input id="areacode" name="areacode" maxlength="3" class="required number" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" />
    <input id="phoneone" name="phoneone" maxlength="3" class="required number" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" />
    <input id="phonetwo" name="phonetwo" maxlength="4" class="required number" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" />
    <button id="phone_submit" type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
```

Now I want to prevent users from filling out this form, not submitting. The backend will block that if they disable the javascript, etc. The backend is also sending a "readonly" attribute back to the first form's input field on valid submit.

So the jQuery could essentially look to see if the first form input is readonly and if not, disable the other form. I don't want to hide it, I just want all the fields and button to be disabled.

I'm thinking there has to already be a plugin that can do something like this or a jquery function that can at least check the first form's input field. So far I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        if $('#password').attr('readonly',true){
            $('#areacode').attr('disabled',true);
            $('#phoneone').attr('disabled',true);
            $('#phonetwo').attr('disabled',true);
            $('#phone_submit').attr('disabled',true);
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this with a simple if statement and showing and hiding an overlay. I first did it with adding a disabled attribute but I wanted the overlay and so it didn't make sense to do it both ways.

Not as semantic as some would like but it works perfectly. Code below is inline styles for readability.

Soooooo....html:

```
<form>
    <input id="password" type="text" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<fieldset style="position: relative;">
    <div class="overlay" style="width:100%;height:100%; position: absolute; top:0; left:0; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); color: #fff;">You must fill out the password above.</div>
    <form></form>
</fieldset>
```

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var block = false;
        if ($('#password').attr('readonly')) {
            block = false;
        } else {
            block = true;
        }
        if (block) {
            $('.overlay').css('display','block');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now when the backend makes the password readonly you can use the form in the fieldset. If there is no readonly attribute on the #password input, the form is effectively blocked. Of course, as always, there is backend code preventing the form submission in case someone decides to erase the overlay with firebug or something.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can achieve this using:

```
$('#divID').modal().show();
$('#divID').modal().close();
```

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Comment: I can't put it in a modal. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried something new with form handling that is a bit similar, but as you don't want, shows or hides elements based on other fields.
Luckily, because I'm lazy, to change its behaviour you only need to change 2 lines of code.

It's still very basic and not properly tested but you can find the source on my site
http://geuze.name/html5form/html5form.relate.js (change line 125 and 127)

And a quick demo together with my html5form polyfill on http://geuze.name/html5form/

Even if not exactly what you need, the code might just help you think in a right direction.

**edit**
Adding code because apparent lazy server ;)

```
/*
 *  Form Relationship Plugin - jQuery plugin
 *  Version 0.2
 * 
 * Built for the jQuery library
 * http://jquery.com
 * 
 * Plugin allows you to easily add smart relations between form fields and other elements
 * 
 *
 */

(function($){
    $.fn.relate = function(options){
        // Uncomment string below during testing
        "use strict";
        var tmp = {},
        // Default configuration properties
            defaults = {
                scoreRequired: 1,
                scoreOnTrue: 1,
                scoreOnFalse: 0,
                globalScope: true,
                debug: false
            },
            callbacks = {
                oninitialize:  function(){},// Runs once per form
                onfinish:      function(){}// Runs once after no errors
            },
            opts = $.extend(
                    {},
                    defaults,
                    callbacks,
                    options
            );
        // Force debug false on sucky browsers
        if(typeof(console)  === 'undefined' || typeof(console.info)  === 'undefined'){
            opts.debug = false;
        }
        // Our debug output
        function debug(str){
            if(opts.debug === true){
                console.info(str);
            }
        };
        // Helper function to determine object size
        function objSize(obj) {
            var size = 0, key;
            for (key in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
            }
            return size;
        };

        // Update per element
        // Easier would be to always loop over everything, but I assume this is faster
        function update(form){
            var related,
                currentScore = 0,
                scoreOnTrue = 1,
                scoreOnFalse = 0;

            // Reset score
            $('[data-currentscore]').removeAttr('data-currentscore');
            // Loop all possible smart elements
            $('select[data-relate], select:has(option[data-relate]), input[data-relate], textarea[data-relate]', form).each(function(){
                if($(this).is('select')){
                    $('option', this).each(function(){
                        // Find relation
                        related = $(this).attr('data-relate');
                        // If no relation, no points to anything
                        if(!related || related.length  0 ? $(this).attr('data-scoreontrue') * 1 : opts.scoreOnTrue;
                        scoreOnFalse = $(this).filter('[data-scoreonfalse]').length > 0 ? $(this).attr('data-scoreonfalse') * 1 : opts.scoreOnFalse;
                        if($(this).is(':selected')){
                            $(related).each(function(){
                                currentScore = $(this).filter('[data-currentscore]').length > 0 ? $(this).attr('data-currentscore') * 1 : 0;
                                $(this).attr('data-currentscore', currentScore + scoreOnTrue);
                            });
                        } else {
                            $(related).each(function(){
                                currentScore = $(this).filter('[data-currentscore]').length > 0 ? $(this).attr('data-currentscore') * 1 : 0;
                                $(this).attr('data-currentscore', currentScore - scoreOnFalse);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    // Find relation
                    related = $(this).attr('data-relate');
                    // If no relation, no points to anything
                    if(!related ||related.length  0  ? $(this).attr('data-scoreontrue') * 1 : opts.scoreOnTrue;
                    scoreOnFalse = $(this).filter('[data-scoreonfalse]').length > 0  ? $(this).attr('data-scoreonfalse') * 1 : opts.scoreOnFalse;
                    if($(this).is('input:radio') || $(this).is('input:checkbox')){
                        if($(this).is(':checked')){
                            $(related).each(function(){
                                currentScore = $(this).filter('[data-currentscore]').length > 0 ? $(this).attr('data-currentscore') * 1 : 0;
                                $(this).attr('data-currentscore', currentScore + scoreOnTrue);
                            });
                        } else {
                            $(related).each(function(){
                                currentScore = $(this).filter('[data-currentscore]').length > 0 ? $(this).attr('data-currentscore') * 1 : 0;
                                $(this).attr('data-currentscore', currentScore + scoreOnFalse);
                            });
                        }
                    } else if($(this).val() !== '' && $(this).val() != $(this).attr('placeholder')){
                        $(related).each(function(){
                            currentScore = $(this).filter('[data-currentscore]').length > 0 ? $(this).attr('data-currentscore') * 1 : 0;
                            $(this).attr('data-currentscore', currentScore + scoreOnTrue);
                        });
                    } else {
                        $(related).each(function(){
                            currentScore = $(this).filter('[data-currentscore]').length > 0 ? $(this).attr('data-currentscore') * 1 : 0;
                            $(this).attr('data-currentscore', currentScore + scoreOnFalse);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
            // Finaly loop over all fields with some sort of score
            $('[data-currentscore]').each(function(){
                var scoreRequired = $(this).has('[data-scorerequired]') ? $(this).attr('data-scorerequired') * 1 : opts.scoreRequired;
                if($(this).attr('data-currentscore') * 1 >= scoreRequired * 1){
                    $(this).show();
                } else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });

        };

        // Loop over all forms requested
        this.each(function(){
            // Private properties
            var form = $(this);

            // Init / change / keyup(fixes some browsers on select)
            update(form);
            $('select[data-relate], select:has(option[data-relate]), input[data-relate], textarea[data-relate]')
            .change(function(){
                update(form);
            }).keyup(function(){
                update(form);
            });
        });
        return this;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Usage as follows:
`$('form').relate({...});` and some html data attributes

Comment: Interesting, never had problems reaching my website from anywhere. I'll paste the code in my message. But it's a bit long.

Comment: I can view the links now. Maybe there was just an intermittent problem earlier today.